# Coordinates Reprojection with GDAL in C++

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, c++

So I am trying to re-project a coordinate from WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N (Meters) to WGS 84 (DD). I have tried the below methods but both times when it gets to the portion to translate it throws Unhandled exception at 0x00007ff62fb056d5 in GDALTestApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000. I am using VS 2012 to run an compile.

Code Sample 1:

```
    OGRSpatialReference srFrom;
    srFrom.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
    srFrom.SetUTM(33, true);

    OGRSpatialReference srTo;
    srTo.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");

    OGRCoordinateTransformation* coordTrans = 
    OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&srFrom, &srTo);

    double x1 = 1291784.057793292;
    double y1 = 2724159.114436987;

    int reprojected = coordTrans->Transform(1, &x1, &y1);
```

Sample 2:

```
    char **sr = nullptr;
    char *srTmpPtr = nullptr;
    GDALTransformerFunc transformer = nullptr;
    void *transformArg;
    GDALDatasetH srcDS = nullptr;
    GDALDatasetH dstDS = nullptr;
    double x1 = 1291784.057793292;
    double y1 = 2724159.114436987;
    double dfZ = 0.0;
    int bSuccess = TRUE;

    //Init the GDAL Lib
    GDALAllRegister();

    //Process the spatial reference conversions
    //Set the Destination
    srTmpPtr = SanitizeSRS("EPSG:4326");
    sr = CSLSetNameValue(sr, "DST_SRS", srTmpPtr);
    CPLFree(srTmpPtr);

    //Set the Originating
    srTmpPtr = SanitizeSRS("EPSG:32633");
    sr = CSLSetNameValue(sr, "SRC_SRS", srTmpPtr);
    CPLFree(srTmpPtr);

    //Create a transformation object from the source to destination coordinate system. 
    transformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;
    transformArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer2( srcDS, dstDS, sr );

    //Clean Up
    CSLDestroy(sr);

    transformer(transformArg, FALSE, 1, &x1, &y1, &dfZ, &bSuccess);
```

Update -- Here is the list of requested files located in my GDAL_DATA directory:
compdcs.csv
coordinate_axis.csv
cubewerx_extra.wkt
datum_shift.csv
ecw_cs.wkt
egm08_25.gtx
ellipsoid.csv
epsg.wkt
esri_extra.wkt
esri_StatePlane_extra.wkt
esri_Wisconsin_extra.wkt
gcs.csv
gcs.override.csv
gdalicon.png
GDALLogoBW.svg
GDALLogoColor.svg
GDALLogoGS.svg
gdalvrt.xsd
gdal_datum.csv
geoccs.csv
geos.dll
gml_registry.xml
gt_datum.csv
gt_ellips.csv
header.dxf
inspire_cp_BasicPropertyUnit.gfs
inspire_cp_CadastralBoundary.gfs
inspire_cp_CadastralParcel.gfs
inspire_cp_CadastralZoning.gfs
netcdf_config.xsd
nitf_spec.xml
nitf_spec.xsd
ogrvrt.xsd
osmconf.ini
ozi_datum.csv
ozi_ellips.csv
pci_datum.txt
pci_ellips.txt
pcs.csv
pcs.override.csv
pdalcpp.dll
PDALManifest.xml
PDALManifest2.xml
pdal_util.dll
prime_meridian.csv
proj.dll
projop_wparm.csv
ruian_vf_ob_v1.gfs
ruian_vf_st_uvoh_v1.gfs
ruian_vf_st_v1.gfs
ruian_vf_v1.gfs
s57agencies.csv
s57attributes.csv
s57attributes_aml.csv
s57attributes_iw.csv
s57expectedinput.csv
s57objectclasses.csv
s57objectclasses_aml.csv
s57objectclasses_iw.csv
seed_2d.dgn
seed_3d.dgn
stateplane.csv
trailer.dxf
unit_of_measure.csv
vdv452.xml
vdv452.xsd
vertcs.csv
vertcs.override.csv

--Update 2: Call stack view:
[image]

--Update 3: Call Stack with symbols downloaded:

[image]

-- Update 4: It appears that the coordTrans is returning a null pointer for some reason even though the code has been tested by other users and works.

-- Solution: The fix ended up being the missing proj.dll.

Comment: Your first example works for me on Linux and your code seems fine.  Have you installed the `gdal-data` directory from GDAL correctly, and set the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable?  Does your program work if you copy the `gdal-data` directory from GDAL into the same directory as your program?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Update, so I actually did have that variable set. The directory contains 61 files. I can list them out in an update up top.

Comment: @CandyGumdrop No change if files are added directory into output directory either

Comment: Do you get any more information from the call stack when debugging in Visual Studio?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop I added the call stack image above. Does that help?

Comment: Do you have the PROJ.4 library installed and set up?  You should have a `proj.dll` file somewhere and GDAL also has a `PROJ_LIB` environment variable which should point to the installation.  Also, which line is line 22 in your example?  Is it the `coordTrans->transform()` line?  Could you also try printing out the value of `CPLGetLastErrorMsg()` after each function call?  (I'm pretty sure these errors should print to your console via stderr anyway though.)

Comment: @CandyGumdrop so it appears the coordTrans pointer is coming back null after all. Do you think that could be the result of the missing libraries and variables?

Comment: @CandyGumdrop The CPLGetLastErrorMsg() is returning 0x00000000036f3d48 "Unable to load PROJ.4 library (proj.dll), creation of
OGRCoordinateTransformation failed."

Comment: @CandyGumdrop Do you know where I can download the pre-compiled windows binary?

Comment: I was missing the proj.dll dependency required by GDAL

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that GDAL needs to dynamically load the PROJ.4 library at runtime in order to use coordinate transformation functions, but PROJ.4 is not installed on your system.  This is why the `OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation` failed with an error and returned `NULL`.

Windows builds of PROJ.4 are available as a package in the [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) software distribution.